# Centralized Database Backup Server

Tags: sql-server, mysql, backup, database, sql

We have database servers running on MySQL and Microsoft SQL. Is there a software that can do automated backups to all our database servers?
I've already evaluated zrm of mysql(no web access,hard to configure), bacula(only on mysql), and navicat(I like the well-designed GUI but it doesn't support ms sql). What are other tools out there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[BackupPC](http://backuppc.sf.net/) can execute pre-backup commands and post-backup commands. That makes it possible to backup MySQL: first just execute mysqldump (or whatever you use), then let BackupPC to backup the dump, and as a post-command remove the dump.

If there's a way to command MSSQL like that remotely, then the same strategy would work for it, too.

Comment: But that means that I still need to log in to all the database servers then create scripts for each to make a backup. What we need is a single server that will handle/manage all database backup. Is there such a software/program? It would be best if its open source.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is nothing like that right now available. I'm working on this kind of application but it is far from finished.

Comment: jose, what's so bad about having to script a bit? scripts are often better, as you can edit them to match your needs

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is easy - backup / restore is done via SQL commands. So, at the end you take a live backup, then copy the file over, OR install a local agend.

Pretty much EVERY (!) enterprise backup software can handle multiple datbase types and srvers. Go out and get one / some for evaluation. Offers are out from Microsoft, CA, Symantec and maybe a dozen others.